# data structure for treeview

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'd like to implement a "TreeView" as a visual mapping of a tree to a list, the indentation in the list being provided by the depth of the mapped node. My concrete problem is a tree 2 levels deep with 100 000 nodes on the first level, each node containing 20 nodes (i.e. 100 000 folders, each containing 20 files). Currently I maintain the mapping from the tree in a `std::map`, which for a fully expanded tree (2 000 000 potentially visible items in the "TreeView") looks like this:

```
key  value
0    pointer to parent node 0
20   pointer to parent node 1
40   pointer to parent node 2
...
```

This means list items [0, 19] are covered by parent node 0, [20, 39] by parent node 1, ... If I collapse node 0, the mapping needs to be updated:

```
key  value
0    pointer to parent node 0
1    pointer to parent node 1
21   pointer to parent node 2
...
```

Here, list item 0 is covered by parent node 0, list items [1, 20] by parent node 1, ... Which means the keys of 99 000 values in the `std::map` need to be updated when collapsing node 0. This means 99 000 deletions and insertions into the map, as the keys cannot be updated otherwise. What data structure and/or container would allow me to update the mapping tree -> list with less effort?

Comment: Typically hundreds of thousands lines are not visible all at once. AFAIK implementations usually don't necessarily hold the data to all nodes in memory at once but rather fetch them on an as-needed basis, saving them from having to insert, remove or whatever 90.000 nodes no one would ever notice as they aren't visible at all at the moment.

Comment: 100k updates at once will impact your app anyway, there's no avoiding that, but you could start by moving to `std::unordered_map` unless you really need the ordering, that should make things an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: @mikyra True, true, but I still need to know, if someone scrolls to an arbitrary position, what to show there, i.e. which nodes to load.

Comment: @user1095108 At an arbitrary position you would need to show/load the node at that arbitrary position.

Comment: @TC1 `std::map` allows me to show a specific item in the list, when I need to show it with it's `upper_bound` member function. For list item 10, say, I call `upper_bound(10)` and get an iterator to the second element in the `std::map`, from which I subtract 1 and obtain the parent node I need to display list item 10.

Comment: Collapsing the parent node shouldn’t necessitate an update to all child nodes. I don’t understand what the keys represent in your example but I think you don’t need to modify them. *Even if* it turns out you need to modify the nodes on every parent update (but really …!), do not store that information in the key – regard keys as constant during a node’s lifetime.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not asking for a data structure/container that stores a tree, but for a data structure/container that stores a mapping from a tree to a list.

Comment: @user1095108 That doesn’t change what I said. Nevertheless it would help if you would *describe* both the list and the mapping in more detail.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Say I scroll to list item number 20 000. What list item (node) to display depends on the collapsed/expanded state of the nodes. I cannot afford a depth-first search in my tree for node number 20 000 every time a scroll occurs (when the mouse moves while dragging the vertical scroll handle).

Comment: @user1095108 is the `key` here the pixel offset of the row in the tree for a given node?

Comment: @je4d No, it's the row number in the list to which a node is mapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like something you can use an augmented tree for. It'll make updating those keys take logarithmic time, and lookup by key will also be logarithmic time.

Unfortunately, I can't write a full answer here and now as I need to head out, but hopefully this article will help: http://je4d.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/boostintrusive-annotated-trees-part-1.html